# How to interpret the venn diagram and answer the two questions on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a survey of 1000 households, washing machines,vacuum cleaners and refrigerators were counted. 400 had no refrigerators, 380 had no vacuum cleaners and 542 had no washing machines. 294 had both vacuum cleaner and washing machine.
(1)how many households had all the three appliances
(2)how many households had only a vacuum cleaner

Comment: Better if you tell us something about what you know about the problem, how far you get, where you get stuck, and so on. This isn't a place for just dumping homework problems --- it's a place for teaching and active learning.

Comment: In simple terms I am failing to come up with a venn diagram

Comment: Not enough information.  As a minimum, it's possible that the answer to both questions is $0$.  As a maximum, they could be $294$ and $326$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first attempt at a Venn diagram where I've tried to make it as general as possible.  (Note that the sizes of the figures are not to scale.)  The sample space is the 1000 households (black) of which 600 have refrigerators (red), 620 have vacuum cleaners (blue), and 458 have washing machines (brown).

We also know that 294 have a vacuum cleaner and a washing machine.  This is a little vague.  I'll assume the more general case that the 294 have *at least* a vacuum cleaner and a washing machine; some of them could also have a refrigerator.  That is, I'll assume $|V\cap W|=294$ (purple).

[image]

Now let's try to get additional information that might help us make the Venn diagram more accurate.

1. Some people have both refrigerators and vacuum cleaners ($R\cap V\ne\emptyset$) because otherwise there would be 1220 households.
2. Some people have both refrigerators and washing machines ($R\cap W\ne\emptyset$) because otherwise there would be 1058 households.
3. Some people have both vacuum cleaners and washing machines ($V\cap W\ne\emptyset$) because otherwise there would be 1078 households.
4. Some people have washing machines but not vacuum cleaners ($W\not\subseteq V$) because otherwise the purple region would have 458 elements.
5. Some people have vacuum cleaners but not refrigerators ($V\not\subseteq R$) because $|V|>|R|$.
6. Some people have refrigerators but not washing machines ($R\not\subseteq W$) because $|R|>|W|$.
7. Some people have vacuum cleaners but not washing machines ($V\not\subseteq W$) because $|V|>|W|$.
8. $|R\cup V\cup W|=|R|+|V|+|W|-|R\cap V|-|R\cap W|-|V\cap W|+|R\cap V\cap W|\le 1000$.
   Thus, $600+620+458-|R\cap V|-|R\cap W|-|V\cap W|+|R\cap V\cap W|\le 1000$ and $|R\cap V\cap W|\le|R\cap V|+|R\cap W|+|V\cap W|-678$.

This seems to be all the information I could get for now.  Note the inequality involving the intersection of $R$, $V$, and $W$.  We won't get an equation unless we get additional information.  (For example, do all of the households have at least one appliance?)